# Send chart to controller asp mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following code in the razor view

```
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Model.chartVM
</div>
```

I use this actionLink to send chart value to controller

```
@Html.ActionLink("click", "DownloadPDF", "PDF", @Model.chartVM, new { @class = "displayPdf" })
```

to get it back in the controller (PDFController) i'm using

```
  public ActionResult DownloadPDF(Chart_Event ce){

         string str = ce.chartVM.GetHashCode().ToString();
    return View()

}
```

The probleme is the value of "ce" in the controller stays empty please why ?

Here is my Model

```
    public class Chart_Event
    {

        public Full fullVM { get; set; }
        public Highcharts chartVM { get; set; }
        public HelpModel helpVM { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your model?

Comment: BTW you will have to post via form

Comment: Is @Model.chartVM null? Do you try model binding?

Comment: Model.chartVm in the view is a chart that is showing fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Model.chartVM
</div>
```

You cannot post complex object like this, if that is what you are trying to achieve.

Neither like this:

`@Html.ActionLink("click", "DownloadPDF", "PDF", @Model.chartVM, new { @class = "displayPdf" })`

If your `Highcharts chartVM` properties are populated, you can provide Hidden Inputs and POST them to your controller like this.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    ......
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.chartVM.PropertyName)
    </div>
    ......
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this I hope it will works.

```
@Html.ActionLink("click", "DownloadPDF", "PDF", new { @class = "displayPdf",cv=@Model.chartVM })
```